# Electronics laboratory op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I'm making the following circuit:

> Given a source that can be represented as a voltage generator that
> generates signals in the range of -1.5 V to -1 V, having a series
> resistance of 100 Ω, design and manufacture an amplifier, even
> multi-stage, that meets the following characteristics:
>
> - The output signal must be between 0 and 5 V + 5%
> - The frequency response must have a low-pass characteristic with a cut-off frequency of 40 kHz ± 10%

The op-amps that I can use are:

- UA741
- LM358
- MCP6292
- OP07

Because my idea was to use an input buffer to reduce noise I had to apply a first-order low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency of 40 kHz.
Finally I wanted to amplify the signal and use an adder so I could get the desired signal.
I'll show you the calculations below. Would you have any advice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you add the calculations and ask a specific question, because the answer to your only question if there is any advice is simply yes.

Comment: You should choose your op-amp based on what power supply is available to use. Don't let the tail wag the dog in other words and, don't use a 741 because they are really poor devices.

Comment: Can you include a schematic of what you have designed/planned thus far?  It is difficult to give much assistance from only a limited written description.

Comment: yes, please show us the calculations, as promised! Together with a schematic, so we can follow them. Do that within your question! That's good preparation for a lab, by the way, so you're going about this the right way.

Comment: I added my scheme according to you it is only achievable with 3 stages
Also, are the formulas correct?
I had checked that I have to power the opamps at least at +10V and -10V to avoid risking saturation problems
I was also thinking of using LM358, but I don't know what gain to give for each stage
do you have any advice?